# Attach taskRoleArn to AWS Fargate does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to attach the IAM role to AWS Fargate container. There is no error and the container could execute. However, the container could not call the AWS API.

From the container:

- When run `aws` command, I got the `Unable to locate credentials`
   error
- `curl` to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info does not success

My task definition:

```json
{
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::my-account-id:role/test-ecs-role",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "Fargate",
          "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "my-app"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "my-account-id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app/submit_data:3e87860f128a286d9b557c90664ad99c",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "my-app"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "2048",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::my-account-id:role/MasterFargate",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:my-account-id:task-definition/my-app:10",
  "family": "my-app",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "256",
  "revision": 10,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "volumes": []
}
```

What should I do to get it work? Thanks.

Comment: What SDK (including version) are you using inside the container to make AWS API calls?

Comment: I use the `awscli` version 1.11.129

Comment: That version's over a year old at this point (released December 2016), I'd try updating the `awscli` version as a first port of call, although that version was cut after the launch of task roles so it _should_ work correctly with the credentials chain for containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same symptoms, my issue was resolved by installing the latest `awscli` via pip rather than using the packaged version.

Older versions (for example one available in ubuntu trusty) do not support being run from Fargate.